# Is there a way to bring the ProcessDate value in First table based on the cumulative total of a column in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have 2 tables:

Table1 Definition:

```sql
-- Table 1 Definition
drop table if exists #Table1
create table #Table1
(
    TREATY_COMPANY_CODE varchar(3),
    CURRENCY varchar(3),
    ProcessDate date,
    RowNumber int,
    Payment_Total decimal(20, 2)
)

insert into #Table1
values 
    ('165', 'USD', '2019-12-31', 1, 32929.92),
    ('165', 'USD', '2019-11-14', 2, 2400.0),
    ('165', 'USD', '2019-10-22', 3, 635.0),
    ('165', 'USD', '2019-03-28', 4, -21808.25),
    ('165', 'USD', '2019-02-13', 5, 54906.57)
```

Table2 Definition:

```sql
drop table if exists #Table2
create table #Table2
(
    PolicyNo int null,
    ZeylRankNo int null,
    TreatyCompanyCode nvarchar(3) null,
    CurrencyType nvarchar(3) null,
    DisposedDate datetime null,
    ProvinceNo nvarchar(3) null,
    GWP decimal(20, 5) null,
    Commission_Received decimal(20, 5) null,
    PrKom decimal(20, 5) null
)
insert into #Table2
values
    ('50620211','0','165','USD',43717,'902','146.45','48.81','97.64'),
    ('12789054','0','165','USD',43717,'902','41.11','13.7','27.41'),
    ('12099876','0','165','USD',43717,'701','1312.44','437.44','875'),
    ('12125423','0','165','USD',43717,'701','0','0','0'),
    ('56718901','0','165','USD',43717,'719','1500','499.95','1000.05'),
    ('23456791','0','165','USD',43717,'720','1500','499.95','1000.05'),
    ('21090323','0','165','USD',43702,'720','2000','500','1500'),
    ('21201921','0','165','USD',43698,'719','1500','724.95','775.05'),
    ('45231905','0','165','USD',43698,'720','1500','724.95','775.05'),
    ('45129834','0','165','USD',43675,'719','1500','499.65','1000.35'),
    ('27819123','0','165','USD',43675,'720','8876','2219','6657'),
    ('28917634','0','165','USD',43675,'701','13953','3488.25','10464.75'),
    ('23179001','0','165','USD',43675,'720','2500','500','2000'),
    ('90030602','0','165','USD',43628,'720','1500','724.95','775.05'),
    ('30402213','0','165','USD',43596,'720','1500','725.1','774.9'),
    ('34244590','0','165','USD',43561,'902','262.22','102.27','159.95'),
    ('12893498','0','165','USD',43561,'701','0','0','0'),
    ('12357634','0','165','USD',43561,'720','1500','724.95','775.05'),
    ('19092334','0','165','USD',43561,'902','273.02','106.48','166.54'),
    ('19003023','0','165','USD',43561,'701','1571.76','612.99','958.77'),
    ('19917823','1','165','USD',43548,'720','-11029','-2680.05','-8348.95'),
    ('29912365','0','165','USD',43515,'902','519.4','103.88','415.52'),
    ('76290123','0','165','USD',43515,'701','1980.6','396.12','1584.48'),
    ('90817623','0','165','USD',43507,'720','13536','3289.25','10246.75'),
    ('23158723','0','165','USD',43442,'720','2500','500','2000'),
    ('23878123','0','165','USD',43341,'701','0','0','0'),
    ('23198323','0','165','USD',43341,'902','2994.9','748.73','2246.17'),
    ('14712345','0','165','USD',43302,'720','1500','724.95','775.05')
```

If cumulative total in [Pr-Kom] Column in Table2 exceeds the 1st number (payment_total:32929,92) in table1, then bring the ProcessDate value to all rows, then move on to next number(2400) , calculate cumulative total and do the same!

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT
       KT.*
       ,(
       CASE WHEN CumulativeTotal <= (SELECT Payment_Total FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber = 1)  THEN CAST('2019-12-31' AS date)
       WHEN CumulativeTotal <= (SELECT Payment_Total FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber = 2) THEN CAST('2019-11-14' AS date)
       WHEN CumulativeTotal <= (SELECT Payment_Total FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber = 3) THEN CAST('2019-10-22' AS date)
       WHEN CumulativeTotal <= (SELECT Payment_Total FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber = 4) THEN CAST('2019-03-28' AS date)
       WHEN CumulativeTotal <= (SELECT Payment_Total FROM Table1 WHERE RowNumber = 5) THEN CAST('2019-02-13' AS date)
       ELSE CAST('1900-01-01' AS date) END
       ) AS Date
FROM(
SELECT
       K.*
       ,SUM(K.[Pr-Kom]) OVER(ORDER BY K.RN) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM
(SELECT
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DisposedDate) AS RN
FROM Table2
WHERE TreatyCompanyCode='165'
AND CurrencyType='USD'
) AS K
) AS KT
```

Expected Result Should be like this:

[image: DER]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Xedni I tried to solve it using window function; but not have chance to use 'partition by' ; cause no suitable column to define each frame(partition). Maybe I am looking for a different way to solve this.

Comment: Do you have the query you tried so far (even if it's wrong)? I'm assuming you're sorting on `DisposedDate` but since there are duplicates in that column, I can't be sure how you've ordered the data.

Comment: @Xedni I have added what I have tried so far. Please check it at the bottom. Thank you!

Comment: One problem here is that you have duplicate `DisposedDate` values. Even though you have a `row_number` over that field, the order within those dates is not guaranteed. In otherwords, if two people run the same query, where that cumulative sum surpasses the other value might change. Your sample output doesn't seem to have any cutoff points like that, but it's a problem I keep coming back to when looking at your problem.

Comment: @Xedni , I don't want to break the data entry sequence (take it in the order it is entered) by ordering by DisposedDate. How can I split this data into 3 or more colors(partitions) with or without using window functions?

Comment: That's the problem though. The data entry sequence is explicitly _not_ maintained once you put it in a relational database. Without a field to deterministically order by, you CANNOT guarantee the order. I noticed in your sample output your `PolicyNo` values _seemed_ to work as a deterministic sort order, but in the sample data, the `PolicyNo` values are different. Maybe a solution can be derived using that, but if those `PolicyNo` values are different, the output is going to be different also.

Comment: Yes, You're right about the data being nondeterministic. Also, I don't want PolicyNo to be involved in any sort operation. By the way, I updated Policy values in the resulting screen to match source data

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example with recursive query.
Ordering Table2 rows significantly discussed with @Xedni. I will take `order by DisposeDate desc` as default.

```
with dn as( -- data with ordering number
select PolicyNo,DisposedDate,ProvinceNo,GWP,Commission_Received
  ,[Pr-Kom],TreatyCompanyCode
  ,row_number()over(partition by TreatyCompanyCode order by DisposedDate desc) rnd
from Table2
)
,r as( -- anchor first row from table1 and first row of table2 with partition
  select PolicyNo,DisposedDate,ProvinceNo,GWP,Commission_Received,[Pr-Kom],rnd  
    ,Payment_total as checkTotal,cast([Pr-Kom] as decimal(20,5)) as currTotal
    ,t1.RowNumber,t1.Payment_Total,t1.ProcessDate,t1.TREATY_COMPANY_CODE,t1.CURRENCY    
  from table1 t1 inner join dn on t1.TREATY_COMPANY_CODE= dn.TREATYCOMPANYCODE
  where t1.rownumber=1 and dn.rnd=1
  union all
  select dn.PolicyNo,dn.DisposedDate,dn.ProvinceNo,dn.GWP,dn.Commission_Received
    ,dn.[Pr-Kom],dn.rnd 
    ,case 
         when cast(r.currTotal as decimal(20,5))> r.checkTotal
            then t1.Payment_total 
     else r.CheckTotal 
     end  as checkTotal
    ,case 
          when cast(r.currTotal as decimal(20,5))> r.checkTotal
            then cast(dn.[Pr-Kom] as decimal(20,5)) 
     else cast(r.currTotal+dn.[Pr-Kom] as decimal(20,5))
     end as currTotal
    ,t1.RowNumber,t1.Payment_Total,t1.ProcessDate,t1.TREATY_COMPANY_CODE,t1.CURRENCY    
  from r 
  inner join dn on r.TREATY_COMPANY_CODE= dn.TREATYCOMPANYCODE
     and dn.rnd=(r.rnd+1)
  inner join table1 t1 on t1.TREATY_COMPANY_CODE= r.TREATY_COMPANY_CODE
    and(case when r.checkTotal>cast(r.currTotal as decimal(20,5)) 
         then r.RowNumber else r.rowNumber+1 end= t1.RowNumber )
)
select * from r
```

[fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/waKcH1Ey)

Comment: another very good solution. Thank you for the time you assigned to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

So this is not a very elegant answer, but it was the best I could come up with.

First, a caveat. Without a deterministic way to order the rows, I don't believe this is possible with SQL. You *need* to be able to identify where one partition ends, and the other begins, and you simply can't do that if you don't have a way to know which row precedes another.

Perhaps you can alter your data processing mechanism to add a surrogate key or something to enforce order. If that's not possible, then I've got nothing.

With that out of the way, maybe someone can come up with a cleaner answer, but I wasn't able to come up with anything that doesn't involve the dreaded loop.

For every iteration, I'm getting the running total of the *remaining* records. On the first loop, that's everything, starting at `RID = 1`. On the second loop, that's everything starting *after* whatever you set in the first pass.

From there, I'm getting the max RID plus one to account for the fact that you want the first row that *exceeds* the threshold from table1.

```
drop table if exists #T1
create table #T1
(
    RowNumber int,
    ProcessDate date,
    PaymentTotal decimal(20, 2)
)

drop table if exists #T2
create table #T2
(
    RID int,
    PolicyNo int,
    DisposedDate datetime null,
    PrKom decimal(20, 5) null,
    PartitionRunningTotal decimal(20, 5) null,
    GroupId int null, -- Going to update this in a loopdy-loop to join #T1 to later
    ProcessDate date
)
go
insert into #T1
values 
    (1,'2019-12-31',32929.92),
    (2,'2019-11-14',2400.0),
    (3,'2019-10-22',635.0),
    (4,'2019-03-28',-21808.25),
    (5,'2019-02-13',54906.57)

insert into #T2 (RID, PolicyNo, DisposedDate, PrKom)
values
    ( 1, 50620211, N'2019-09-11T00:00:00', 97.64000 ),
    ( 2, 12789054, N'2019-09-11T00:00:00', 27.41000 ),
    ( 3, 12099876, N'2019-09-11T00:00:00', 875.00000 ),
    ( 4, 12125423, N'2019-09-11T00:00:00', 0.00000 ),
    ( 5, 56718901, N'2019-09-11T00:00:00', 1000.05000 ),
    ( 6, 23456791, N'2019-09-11T00:00:00', 1000.05000 ),
    ( 7, 21090323, N'2019-08-27T00:00:00', 1500.00000 ),
    ( 8, 21201921, N'2019-08-23T00:00:00', 775.05000 ),
    ( 9, 45231905, N'2019-08-23T00:00:00', 775.05000 ),
    ( 10, 45129834, N'2019-07-31T00:00:00', 1000.35000 ),
    ( 11, 27819123, N'2019-07-31T00:00:00', 6657.00000 ),
    ( 12, 28917634, N'2019-07-31T00:00:00', 10464.75000 ),
    ( 13, 23179001, N'2019-07-31T00:00:00', 2000.00000 ),
    ( 14, 90030602, N'2019-06-14T00:00:00', 775.05000 ),
    ( 15, 30402213, N'2019-05-13T00:00:00', 774.90000 ),
    ( 16, 34244590, N'2019-04-08T00:00:00', 159.95000 ),
    ( 17, 12893498, N'2019-04-08T00:00:00', 0.00000 ),
    ( 18, 12357634, N'2019-04-08T00:00:00', 775.05000 ),
    ( 19, 19092334, N'2019-04-08T00:00:00', 166.54000 ),
    ( 20, 19003023, N'2019-04-08T00:00:00', 958.77000 ),
    ( 21, 19917823, N'2019-03-26T00:00:00', -8348.95000 ),
    ( 22, 29912365, N'2019-02-21T00:00:00', 415.52000 ),
    ( 23, 76290123, N'2019-02-21T00:00:00', 1584.48000 ),
    ( 24, 90817623, N'2019-02-13T00:00:00', 10246.75000 ),
    ( 25, 23158723, N'2018-12-10T00:00:00', 2000.00000 ),
    ( 26, 23878123, N'2018-08-31T00:00:00', 0.00000 ),
    ( 27, 23198323, N'2018-08-31T00:00:00', 2246.17000 ),
    ( 28, 14712345, N'2018-07-23T00:00:00', 775.05000 )

-- GroupID is synonymous with the RowNumber from #T1. 
declare @GroupId int
select @GroupId = min(RowNumber)
from #T1

declare
    @PaymentTotal decimal(20, 5),
    @ProcessDate date,
    @PartitionEndRID int

-- While there are still rows for which we havn't filled in this data...
while exists
(
    select 1
    from #t2
    where GroupId is null
)
begin

    select
        @PaymentTotal = PaymentTotal,
        @ProcessDate = ProcessDate
    from #t1
    where RowNumber = @GroupId

    -- Get the upper boundary of the current partition
    ;with a as
    (
        select
            RID,
            PartitionRunningTotal = sum(PrKom) over (order by RID)
        from #t2
        where GroupId is null
    )
    select @PartitionEndRID = max(a.RID) + 1 -- +1 to account for the value needing to _exceed_ the Payment Total
    from a
    where PartitionRunningTotal < @PaymentTotal

    -- Update everything in T2 (that's not already set) where the RID is less than the upper boundary
    update #T2
    set GroupId = @GroupId,
        ProcessDate = @ProcessDate
    where GroupId is null
    and RID <= @PartitionEndRID

    -- Go again
    select @GroupID += 1

end

-- This yields the output table
select
    RID,
    PolicyNo,
    DisposedDate,
    PrKom,
    RunningTotal = sum(PrKom) over (order by RID),
    PartitionRunningTotal = sum(PrKom) over (partition by GroupId order by RID),
    GroupId,
    ProcessDate
from #T2
order by RID
```

I would love to have come up with a more elegant way to do this, but this is the best I got.

Comment: Thank you very much for your high-quality answer. I learned that we can order the 2nd table by DisposedDate DESC which makes it deterministic. Considering this, can you offer me a suitable answer? I updated Excel screenshot on the post.